# how to encrypt using a private key

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, cryptography, retrofit

I have a Private key file that looks like this

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
[content]
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

i want to encrypt String data using this key

i am trying like this :

```
fun encryptData(txt: String, pk: String): String {
    var encoded = ""
    var encrypted: ByteArray? = null
    try {
        val publicBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(pk, Base64.DEFAULT)
        val keySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes)
        val keyFactory: KeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        val pubKey: PrivateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec)
        val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey)
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(txt.toByteArray())
        encoded = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return encoded
}
```

i am getting a InvalidKeySpecException everytime i try to encode

```
can someone help ?
```

Comment: The private key is not used for encryption, but for signing (or decryption). Also, `X509EncodedKeySpec` is intended for a public key in SPKI format. For a private key in PKCS#8 format `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` has to be used.

Comment: I.e. if `X509EncodedKeySpec` is replaced with `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`, the posted code produces a signature with PKCS#1 v1.5 paddding (where the data is not hashed and therefore the DigestID is not considered).

Comment: i replaced X509EncodedKeySpec with PKCS8EncodedKeySpec now the data returns an encoded string but this string is not accepted in retrofit header.

Comment: Well, then you have to figure out what *retrofit* requires.